# How do I concatenate multiple cells which fulfil a criteria in Sheets/Excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, concatenation

I wish to Concatenate multiple cells together which fulfil a certain criteria of my choosing.

For example, if I want all of the cats or all of the dogs in one cell, even if they duplicate:

```
A1 Cat B2 Leopard 
A2 Dog B3 Hyeenah
A3 Cat C3 Tortoise Shell
A4 Cat C4 Tortoise Shell
```

So I want to Concatenate all of the cats and return in one cell so that the output is: Leopard, Tortoise Shell, Tortoise Shell

or for Dogs:

Hyeenah

I have tried various combinations using Index, Match, Ifs and Concatenate but do not feel like I am getting any closer.

I hope to return the output I specify in a reference cell.

Comment: You need the TEXTJOIN function for this or go with a vba solution. Also why do you go from cell B2 to B3 then C3 and C4?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you actually meant `B1:B4` in the return values, you could use the [`TEXTJOIN`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/textjoin-function-357b449a-ec91-49d0-80c3-0e8fc845691c) function depending on your Excel license. Follow the link to see if it would be available to you.

---

[image]

Unfortunately there is no such thing as a `TEXTJOINIF` function, so we have to create our own.

Formula in `E1`:

```
=TEXTJOIN(", ",TRUE,IF($A$1:$A$4=D1,$B$1:$B$4,""))
```

> ***Note:*** These are array formulas entered as CSE through <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>

---

Might you not have `TEXTJOIN` your best bet is to go with a `UDF`, and we can create our own `TEXTJOINIF` function:

```
Function TEXTJOINIF(Delimiter As String, CriteriaRange1 As Range, Criteria As String, ConcatRange As Range) As String

Dim CL As Range
For Each CL In CriteriaRange1
    If CL.Value = Criteria Then
        If TEXTJOINIF = "" Then
            TEXTJOINIF = ConcatRange.Cells(CL.Row, 1).Value
        Else
            TEXTJOINIF = TEXTJOINIF & Delimiter & ConcatRange.Cells(CL.Row, 1).Value
        End If
    End If
Next CL

End Function
```

You can call it in `E1`:

```
=TEXTJOINIF(", ",$A$1:$A$4,D1;$B$1:$B$4)
```

And drag it down.

Comment: Thank you! I think that brings me close.

Comment: But what happens when I enter that formula is that I actually get leopard, hyeenah, tortoise shell, tortoise shell. Is there any way of exluding criteria you dont want ie in this case, dogs? Thanks!

Comment: @benaspill, yes to enter it as an array formula like I explained with the keys control +shift+ enter. It will work of you have done what I posted

Comment: Ah thanks, will look up array formulas and teach myself! Thanks very much

Comment: I believe I up voted. Worked like a a charm, this is going to help a lot!! Thanks

Comment: @BenAspill, as the owner of the question you can "close" the thread if the answer suits your needs by clicking the "tick" next to my answer as described in the link in my previous comment.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an Excel Wizard, just a programmer, but I believe you need some sort of automation/repetition loop.  I found this can be done with VBA in Excel.

Link: [Excel VBA Loop](https://www.excel-easy.com/vba/loop.html)

Here is the pseudo-code:

```
// SUMMATION CELL CATS: D1
// SUMMATION CELL DOGS: D2

   Dim i As Integer

   For i = 1 To 6
     IF(Cells(i, 1).Value == "Cat"){CONCATENATE(D1, Cells(i,1).Value, ',')}
     ELSE(Cells(i, 1).Value == "Dog"){CONCATENATE(D2, Cells(i,1).Value, ',')}
   Next i
```

I hope that helps you get towards the solution.